# Add test cases to test set using Ruby Rally Rest API

Tags: rally

I'm trying to add test cases to a test set in Rally.

I have the test set object and the test case object.
I can REPLACE the entire test set list with THIS test case object and it works fine.
But I really need to ADD this test case to the list.

Any idea how I do this differently?

testset_object.update(:test_cases => test_case_object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the :test_cases field should just be an array, so this should work:
tests = [test_case_object1, test_case_object2]
testset_object.update(:test_cases => tests)
Hope that helps

Comment: thanks so much, that was exactly what I needed to understand.  I also now see how I can set an array "tests" to existing test set array, then do tests << newtestcase_object to add onto end of existing array. Then set new array back into test set.